# Create Microsoft Access Query In C#

Tags: c#

I can not get the syntax down with the whole double quote single quote in my C# conversion.  I am wanting to run the below syntax which as you can see has both.

I know that in a string in C# you typically convert all double quotes to single quotes, but that throws off my syntax because I can't have single single etc.

The question at hand is, how would I re-write this (which works in access as is) to work in C# to generate the access query?

```
string query1 = "    Select Distinct [D].ID, [A].[Company Name], ConcatRelated("[System Name]", "[A]", "[A].[Company Name] = '" & [A].[Company Name] & "'")
FROM [D] INNER JOIN [A] on [D].[Company Name] = [A].[Company Name];"
```

Comment: escape your quotes with \"

Comment: In C#, if you want a string like "Flydog can [quote]Fly[quote], kinda-sorta", you *escape* the quote with a backslash: "Flydog can \"Fly\", kinda-sorta"

Comment: Am I escaping the double quotes or the single quotes?

Comment: You only need to escape the Double quotes.  Single quotes are fine. Unescaped double quotes signify the end of the string.

Comment: Once I remembered to replace & with + - that worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are running into is caused by not escaping your double (`"`) quotes. You can escape these by proceeding them with `\`.

Example:

```
string strTest = "\"This is a test string\"";
```

Output:

```
"This is a test string"
```